# How to initialize class properties from Query Strings?

Tags: php

I would like to know How to initialize class properties from Query Strings? I am come with following code where I am checking and initializing class properties by checking specific condition.

```
class Sample
{
    var $id;
    var $txtName;

    function Sample()
    {
        if(count($_REQUEST))
        {
            if(array_key_exists("id",$_REQUEST))
                $this->id = $_REQUEST['id'];
            if(array_key_exists("txtName",$_REQUEST))
                $this->txtName = $_REQUEST['txtName'];  
        }
    }

    //other functions
}

//--------------

$obj = new Sample();
$obj->getParam("id");
$obj->getParam("txtName");
```

Is it possible that we extend this `Sample` class from some base class and initialize class properties. For that I have some thought but not clear solution. It's like below

```
class GetQueryStrings
{
    //something like child class can initialize their properties
}
class Sample extends GetQueryStrings
{
    var $id;
    var $txtName;

    function Sample()
    {
        if(count($_REQUEST))
        {
            if(array_key_exists("id",$_REQUEST))
                $this->id = $_REQUEST['id'];
            if(array_key_exists("txtName",$_REQUEST))
                $this->txtName = $_REQUEST['txtName'];  
        }
    }

    //other functions
}

//--------------

$obj = new Sample();
$obj->getParam("id");
$obj->getParam("txtName");
```

Is it possible that by using `$obj->getParam("id");`, can we initialize `$this->id` of `Sample` class without initialize it in its constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class GetQueryStrings
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
        {
            if (property_exists(get_class($this), $key))
                $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure the constructor is called when overriding the constructor:

```
class Derived extends GetQueryString
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        ... other code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Friend +1. It worked what I wanted to do. Again I am appreciating your quick and great solution.

Comment: I would like to ask you one more thing that, Is this proper way what I want to achieve? because using `$_GET['txtName']` is little bit clumsy but if we initialize like what you suggested is better way.